# Android studio doesnt recognize some libraries.(import statements)

Tags: android, android-studio, import

Android studio does not recognize some import statements like

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
```

But it recognizes some import statements like

```
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: how did you use smack lib? Have you declared the lib in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added the necessary dependency in your gradle file and have done a gradle sync to download the required packages

compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.8'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.8'

This worked for me

Comment: I am a newbie in android studio. I did a gradle sync in response to the error message of android studio I think. Can you explain how can I add the necessary dependency

Comment: Add those dependencies to your gradle file and also update the version numbers to 4.1.8

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work. It gives error of coult not file  compile()for arguments smackandroid extensions etc

Comment: add These Two Lines In Your App module Gradle Dependencies

Comment: compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0'

Comment: compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'